# How to burn multiple copies of a cd

Tags: optical-drive, cd-burning

Is there an app or a native way to burn multiple copies of the same CD or DVD on a Mac with OS X in one go? As in, when the first disc is burnt, it pops out and you insert the next disk and it continues until you've done your lot of disks then you stop the process.

For such a basic feature which I've been using ages ago on Windows it seems a bit strange that I cannot find a way of doing it on Mac.

Comment: Yah there are (paid) utilities like Toast that can do this and much more. I haven't used Toast in a long time but it could do it years ago so it should still be able to do this.

Comment: Make an image of the disc in **Disk Utility** and then in **Finder** right-click and select **Burn Disk Image “Filename.cdr” to Disc…**  -- Do the **Finder** bit for however may copies you want to burn and then delete the Filename.cdr disc image. Note that this does not work with an audio CD.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best free one I could find. Does multiples as well.

Disco App
http://www.discoapp.com/

Comment: Right now this reads like an ad. Can you show *how* the task can accomplished with the application?

Comment: **Disco** had not been updated since February 28th 2008 and is no longer being developed or supported. **Disco** is a 32-bit app and will not run on **macOS Catalina**!